# Copy data from one column to multiple columns specifying their name

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way of splitting data from a column into multiple columns but specifying the exact name of the columns I want to copy my data to?
Suppose I have column1 with data separated by a comma in each row and I want to copy that data in columnX, columnY and columnZ?

My data looks like this:

```
column1                     columnX     columnY    columnZ
data1, data2, data3
```

Expected output:

```
column1        columnX     columnY   columnZ
data1          data2       data3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- convert into a `list`
- deal with NaN and none string data types
- expand `'list` to columns using `pd.Series`
- `rename()` columns to required names

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"column1":["1,2,3","4,5,6","",np.nan,"7,8,9,10","a,b",0]})
srccol = "column1"
dstcols = ["columnX","columnY","columnZ"]

df = df.join(df[srccol]
        .fillna("")
        .astype(str)
        .apply(lambda x: x.split(","))
        .apply(pd.Series)
        .rename(columns={i:c for i,c in enumerate(dstcols)}))
```

### output

````
    column1 columnX columnY columnZ    3
0     1,2,3       1       2       3  NaN
1     4,5,6       4       5       6  NaN
2                       NaN     NaN  NaN
3       NaN             NaN     NaN  NaN
4  7,8,9,10       7       8       9   10
5       a,b       a       b     NaN  NaN
6         0       0     NaN     NaN  NaN```
````

Comment: is there a way to prevent errors caused by blank cells?I want to assign to 10 columns but there may not be value for all of them

Comment: I've updated - it would be far better if you provided reproducible example in accordance with SO guideance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `expand=True` parameter of [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"column1": ["a,b,c", "d,e,f"]})

res = pd.concat((df, df.column1.str.split(',', expand=True)), axis=1)
res.columns = df.columns.tolist() + ["columnX","columnY","columnZ"]
```

Result

```
  column1 columnX columnY columnZ
0   a,b,c       a       b       c
1   d,e,f       d       e       f
```

---

Answer for the updated question:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"column1": ["data1, data2, data3"]})
new_cols = ["columnX", "columnY", "columnZ"]

res = df.column1.str.split(',', expand=True)
res.columns = (df.columns.tolist() + new_cols)[:res.shape[1]]
res[new_cols[res.shape[1]-df.shape[1]:]] = np.nan
```

Comment: thank you, is there a way to remove the data from the cell I'm copying? Not all data, for eg I have test1, test2,test3...I split the data in other columns but in this column I want to remain with the first value

Comment: sorry but I don't understand what you want to do - can you give an example of given data and desired result please?

Comment: I have updated the description, thank you